# How do I get a query to return an array in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, database-design

The query code

```
 SELECT * FROM products 
              LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM product_images ) as images ON products.id = images.productId
              LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM product_shippings ) as shipping ON products.id = shipping.productId
              WHERE products.id = :productID
```

I have multiple images in product_images, but it's only returning one instance.

What I want to do is get it all in a associate array, like images containing a list of images, shipping containing a list of shipping items, etc.

I know how to achieve this using separate queries, but that is way too slow according to my benchmarks.

So I want something like

```
 {
images:[...],
shipping[...],
productId:2,
productTitle:'Hello'
}
```

How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
    FROM products 
    LEFT JOIN product_images as images      ON products.id = images.productId
    LEFT JOIN product_shippings as shipping ON products.id = shipping.productId
    WHERE products.id = :productID
```

Or, to get commalists (not "arrays")

```
SELECT  p.id, p.title,
        GROUP_CONCAT(i.image) AS images,
        GROUP_CONCAT(s.shipping) AS shippings
    FROM products AS p
    LEFT JOIN product_images AS i     ON p.id = i.productId
    LEFT JOIN product_shippings AS s  ON p.id = s.productId
    WHERE p.id = :productID
```

Comment: Is what Im trying to achieve even better than running seperate queries to fetch the data individually?

Comment: @calimses - "Better" in what sense?  Multiple queries would be slower (in this case).  It depends on what you do with the results -- which set of output is easiest to work with?  Also, note that `GROUP_CONCAT` has a limit of 1024 bytes, which could lead to chopping off results.

Answer (score 0):

If you take away the GROUP BY you will get all the images for the product.id in the WHERE clause.

Comment: I updated my question, was a bit obtuse but I hope it makes things more clear.